# Modifying a Shader Storage Buffer Object from within a Vertex Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-4

In my base program (C++/OpenGL 4.5) I have copied the content of the *Vertex Buffer* to an *Shader Storage Buffer* (SSBO):

```
float* buffer = (float*) glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3, ssbo[2]);

glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*size,buffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3, 0);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

In the *Vertex Shader* this data is bound to an array:

```
#version 430
#extension GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object : require

layout(shared, binding = 3) buffer storage
{
    float array[];
}
```

But when I'm trying to overwrite an array entry in the `main` function like this:

```
array[index_in_bounds] = 4.2;
```

nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Can I change the buffer from within the Vertex Shader? Is this only possible in a Geometry Shader? Do I have to do this with Transform Feedback (that I have never used before)?

**edit:**
I'm mapping the buffers for test purposes in my main program, just to see if the data changes:

```
float* buffer = (float*) glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
float* ssbo = (float*) glMapNamedBuffer(3, GL_READ_ONLY);

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE_OF_BUFFERS; i++)
    printf("% 5f | % 5f\n", ssbo[i], buffer[i]);

glUnmapNamedBuffer(3);
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

Comment: Define "nothing happens." Show the code where you detect whether something has or has not happened.

Comment: It's obvious as I'm using the array for transformations. I've added my debug output code.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have found the problem using the red book. I have not bound the buffer correctly and binding the buffer base has to happen *after* buffering the data:

```
float* buffer = (float*) glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, &ssbo); // bind buffer

// switched these two:
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*size,buffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3, &ssbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0); // unbind buffer
glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```